# WCF web service gives error after hosting

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services

I have hosted a WCF web service in IIS. But when i fire url I get the following error message.

"IIS specified authentication schemes 'Basic, Anonymous', but the binding only supports specification of exactly one authentication scheme. Valid authentication schemes are Digest, Negotiate, NTLM, Basic, or Anonymous. Change the IIS settings so that only a single authentication scheme is used."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resolve this issue by disabling the basic authentication on your IIS. It depends that which IIS version you are working with? but for IIS 7, you can do this by updating you web.config file as follows:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <authentication>
            <basicAuthentication enabled="false" />
        </authentication>   
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```